# Загрузить (сохранить) картинку из ImageView в папке приложения

Tags: android

Есть активность с `ImageView`. По нажатию на нее из галереи пользователь выбирает картинку и она вставляется в `ImageView`. Мне нужно, чтобы после выборка она (картинка) сохранялась в папке приложения, например "images" или в папке в памяти телефона.

Далее планируется записать название картинки в БД, а при запуске этой активити уже из этой папки выводить картинку в `ImageView`.

Пока что у меня есть вот это

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private ImageView imgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imgView.setClickable(true);

        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentURI) {
        String result = null;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            if(idx >= 0) {
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        switch(requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.this, selectedImage));
                    Toast.makeText(this,"PATH: " + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: четко сформулируйте вопрос

Comment: А что именно непонятно в моем вопросе?

Comment: Мне нужно когда  картинка выбирается из галереи копировать ее в папку с приложением. Например в "images". А в Другом активити будет отображение  (но до этого еще не дошел). Когда буду делать отображение, то выводить в ImageView уже не из галереи, а из папки приложения. Т.к. из галереи пользователь может удалить фотку

Comment: ИМХО если фото удалено, то лучше оповестить пользователя и установить фото по умолчанию, а не создавать вторую галерею на устройстве

Comment: Хотелось бы все-таки эти фото в какую-то папку копировать, на случай если пользователь удалит случайно. Можно например не в папку с приложением, а в другую папку в памяти телефона.

Comment: Обновил вопрос добавил код получения пути выбранного изображения. Как копировать теперь вопрос